# Parse.com Android upload Image "invalid utf-8 string was provided" by RestApi

Tags: android, parse-platform, retrofit

I'm trying send my image file to Parse.com using retrofit lib, but I am getting the following error:

```
{"code":107,"error":"invalid utf-8 string was provided"}
```

On Parse i made a Class "ImageProfile" with a field of kind File, in my client i have this:

```
 @Multipart
 @POST("/classes/ImageProfile")
 void updateUser(@Part("imageFile") TypedFile photo, Callback<Images> callback);
```

**In My Activity**

```
File file = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);

String mimeType = "image/jpeg";
TypedFile fileToSend = new TypedFile(mimeType, file);

 service.updateUser(fileToSend, new Callback<Images>() {

            @Override
            public void success(Images images, Response response) {

                Log.d("tag", "Image Name " + images.getName());
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Log.d("tag", "Error: " + error.toString());
            }
});
```

Log :

```
03-15 13:54:46.921  21520-21855/br.com.andersonacs.sample.retrofit D/Retrofit﹕ <--- HTTP 400  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/ImageProfile (16254ms)
03-15 13:54:46.921  21520-21855/br.com.andersonacs.sample.retrofit D/Retrofit﹕ Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
03-15 13:54:46.921  21520-21855/br.com.andersonacs.sample.retrofit D/Retrofit﹕ Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
03-15 13:54:46.921  21520-21855/br.com.andersonacs.sample.retrofit D/Retrofit﹕ Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
03-15 13:54:46.921  21520-21855/br.com.andersonacs.sample.retrofit D/Retrofit﹕ Date: Sun, 15 Mar 2015 17:55:29 GMT
03-15 13:54:46.921  21520-21855/br.com.andersonacs.sample.retrofit D/Retrofit﹕ Server: nginx/1.6.0
03-15 13:54:46.921  21520-21855/br.com.andersonacs.sample.retrofit D/Retrofit﹕ X-Parse-Platform: G1
03-15 13:54:46.921  21520-21855/br.com.andersonacs.sample.retrofit D/Retrofit﹕ X-Runtime: 0.001086
03-15 13:54:46.921  21520-21855/br.com.andersonacs.sample.retrofit D/Retrofit﹕ Content-Length: 57
03-15 13:54:46.921  21520-21855/br.com.andersonacs.sample.retrofit D/Retrofit﹕ Connection: keep-alive
03-15 13:54:46.921  21520-21855/br.com.andersonacs.sample.retrofit D/Retrofit﹕ OkHttp-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1
03-15 13:54:46.921  21520-21855/br.com.andersonacs.sample.retrofit D/Retrofit﹕ OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1426438486354
03-15 13:54:46.926  21520-21855/br.com.andersonacs.sample.retrofit D/Retrofit﹕ OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1426438486924
03-15 13:54:46.931  21520-21855/br.com.andersonacs.sample.retrofit D/Retrofit﹕ {"code":107,"error":"invalid utf-8 string was provided"}
03-15 13:54:46.931  21520-21855/br.com.andersonacs.sample.retrofit D/Retrofit﹕ <--- END HTTP (57-byte body)
03-15 13:54:46.931  21520-21520/br.com.andersonacs.sample.retrofit D/andre﹕ Error: retrofit.RetrofitError: 400 Bad Request
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved**

I created a class "`ImageProfile`" and added a "`imageFile`" property of the File type, and finally tried to save an image in this property.

this resulted in error `{"code": 107, "error": "invalid utf-8 string was provided"}` because the field "`imageFile`" expects a json.

> file type field in parse.com expects a json with the following
>   structure.
>
> ```
> {
>
>  "field name": {
>       "name": "...image_name.png",
>       "__type": "File"
>     }
> }
> ```

Then I find out that the File type is just a pointer to a file saved by url https://api.parse.com/1/files/name.extension

So we should make a post to https://api.parse.com/1/files/name.extension

for example:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: {APP ID}" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: {REST KEY}" \
  -H "Content-Type: image/jpeg" \
  --data-binary '@mmp.png.jpg' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/files/mmp.png
```

> An important caveat, the Content-Type should be (image / jpeg or png)
>   and not Multipart as expected.
>
> [Multipart form-data is not supported when uploading
>   files](https://www.parse.com/questions/afnetworking20-use-restapi-upload-image-error)

**Reponse :**

```
{
    "name": "tfss-5724175f-74b6-4a03-8443-2ebbaef90ba6-mmp.png",
    "url": "http://files.parsetfss.com/71e6836f-6005-4e8b-a4f7-99154ccf2b33/tfss-5724175f-74b6-4a03-8443-2ebbaef90ba6-mmp.png"
}
```

Now we can associate this image with an object of `ImageProfile` as follows:

```
curl -X PUT \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: APP_ID" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: KEY" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{ "imageFile": { "name": "tfss-5724175f-74b6-4a03-8443-2ebbaef90ba6-mmp.png", "__type": "File" } }' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/ImageProfile/OBJECT_ID
```

**Response :**

```
{
    "imageFile":{
    "__type": "File",
    "name": "tfss-5724175f-74b6-4a03-8443-2ebbaef90ba6-mmp.png",
    "url": "http://files.parsetfss.com/71e6836f-6005-4e8b-a4f7-99154ccf2b33/tfss-5724175f-74b6-4a03-8443-2ebbaef90ba6-mmp.png"
    },
    "updatedAt": "2015-03-17T12:58:23.183Z"
}
```

[Official Documentation](https://parse.com/docs/rest#files)

Answer (score -1):

Your Content-Type is likely causes your error response as you're trying to send a Multipart request with a JPEG image as MimeType. So you're Content-Type should be form/Multipart

Check that your RestAdapter that you're using does not intercept before a application/json header